# $x \ln x$ uniformly continuous in $(0,3]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have to decide if the function $x \ln x$ is uniformly continuous in $(0,3]$.

I could show that $x \ln x$ is defined and continuous in a closed and limited interval. In this situation for Weierstrass I could prove that $x \ln x $ is uniformly continuous in such interval.

And then use the extension theorem  for which $x \ln x$ is uniformly continuous also in a restriction such as $(0,3]$.

But $x \ln x$ is not defined in 0.
Could someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 0+} x \ln x =0$ so $f(x)=x \ln x$ for $0 <x\leq 3, f(0)=0$ defines a continuous function on $[0,3]$. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous and this implies that $x \ln x $ is uniformly continuous $(0,3]$.

To prove that $x \ln x \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$ apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac {\ln x} {1/x}$.

Comment: so i can eliminate the discontinuity putting  $f(x=0)=f^{+}_0$?

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.

Comment: I thought about this solution but it seemed to me impossible because the function is not continuous in $0$

Comment: The function **extends** to a continuous function on $[0,3]$ and this is enough for uniform continuity.

Comment: ok thanks for your help